URL in fetch call is resolving to undefined
I am trying to set an endpoint in my typescript library using the window object. In my global.ts I have the following:
   declare global {
    interface Window {
      DICTIONARY_ENDPOINT_URL: string;
      OTHER_ENDPOINT_URL?: string;
  }
}

function setDictionaryEndpointURL() {
  window.DICTIONARY_ENDPOINT_URL = DISPATCHER_API_HOST + DOWNLOAD_DICTIONARY_BY_LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT;
};

setDictionaryEndpointURL();

In my fetchDictionary.ts I have this fetch call:
function fetchDictionary(
  i18n: I18n,
  feature: string
): Dict | null {
 
  const url = window.DICTIONARY_ENDPOINT_URL;

  const response = fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
  });

  const jsonResponse = response.ok ? response.json().content : null;
  return jsonResponse;
}

The URL is always resolving to undefined.
I've tried changing the fetch method to an async method, but I continue to have the same issue with the URL being undefined.

Why even use globals? If you have a function that knows what the URL should be, then have it return that value. And call it instead of getting the global value.

Unrelated to your current problem: 1. response is actually a promise, so you can't call response.json() unless you used await fetch( /* ... */ ). 2. Even then response.json().content is not what you want: .json() would return a promise and promises don't have a content property. TS should have given you a compilation errors for these.

"I've tried changing the fetch method to an async method..." Good, because the current code is incorrect. fetch and Response's json both return promises, but your code is written to expect them to work synchronously. TypeScript should be telling you that (for instance) there is no ok property, json method, or content property on a promise.

Assuming the code at the top of the question is executed before fetchDictionary is called, and they're in the same environment, there's no reason to think window wouldn't have a value for DICTIONARY_ENDPOINT_URL. Some modern frameworks can make it a bit unclear to someone new to them what code is running on the server and what code is running on the client, and at least one server-side environment (Deno) provides a top-level window global (they may change that). Could the two bits of code be running in different places?

I inherited a partially finished project and I'm working my way through it. I'm also brand new to TS. I have no compilation errors from TS and I previously had const url =  in the fetchDictionary function and the expected content was returned. Is it better to not use the window interface to set this url?

Using globals has been frowned upon since before JS existed.

Typescript is Javascript.  If the code gives you runtime errors, those are javascript errors.

@beans3598 - TypeScript will definitely give you errors on the code in the question: https://tsplay.dev/w2o29N If you're not seeing any, then TypeScript isn't set up correctly in your environment, and that's probably the first thing you'll want to fix. :-)

What are DISPATCHER_API_HOST and DOWNLOAD_DICTIONARY_BY_LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT? How is setDictionaryEndpointURL() invoked? On Document load? Or is it invoked by another function? Does it get invoked before fetchDictionary() or after? There is a data race and that should be your focus.
